# Understanding Message to Self in Akka

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm learning Akka, and i'm trying to develop a very simple PingPong App. 
I want to know why i don't have the desired output, which is :

```
=> Pong
=> Ping
=> Pong
=> Ping 
.....
```

Instead i get just `one => Pong.`

Game App :

```
import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Await

case object Ping
case object Pong

object GamePPApp extends App{
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(2 second)
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("Ping-Pong")

  val gamer1 = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[GamerActor], "gamer1")

  //  gamer1 ! Ping // I tried this too


  // asking for result from actor
  val future = (gamer1 ?  Ping)
  Await.result(future, 2 seconds)

}
```

GamerActor :

```
import akka.actor.Actor

class GamerActor extends Actor{

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Ping =>
      println(s"=> Pong")
      sender ! Pong
    case Pong =>
      println(s"=> Ping")
      sender ! Ping
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why ?

[EDIT] If i change the sender to self, it works, but i want to know why i can't use sender, and in my case i think self is the sender

Thank you

Comment: Well... you are sending the message back to the `sender` and not to `self`

Comment: Yeah but the self is the sender in my case ?

Comment: No, it's still the temporary actor created for the `ask` pattern. Just do a print on the `sender`, and it's gonna be something like `Ping-Pong$a`, and not your `gamer1` actor

Comment: Yes you're right, 
Actor[akka://Ping-Pong/temp/$a]
Actor[akka://Ping-Pong/user/gamer1#-548307841]
From the akka doc : 
"/temp" is the guardian for all short-lived system-created actors, e.g. those which are used in the implementation of ActorRef.ask.
And when i just gamer1 ! Ping 
Actor[akka://Ping-Pong/deadLetters]
Actor[akka://Ping-Pong/user/gamer1#1501020360]
Why exactly ?

Comment: I Just put detailed answer

Answer (score 2):

You are replying to `sender`, and not to `self`, as you wished. It's probably just a typo in your code.

Comment: but the self is the sender in my case ?

Comment: no, the sender is the temporary actor created for the ask pattern

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution, is to pass the ActorRef as Parameter:

Case classes

```
case class Ping(actorRef: ActorRef)
case class Pong(actorRef: ActorRef)
```

Send message :

```
gamer1 ! Ping(gamer1)
```

GameActor :

```
class GamerActor extends Actor{

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Ping(actorRef) =>
      println(s"=> Pong")
      println(actorRef)
      println(self)
      actorRef ! Pong(self)
    case Pong(actorRef) =>
      println(s"=> Ping")
      actorRef ! Ping(self)
  }

}
```

So now self == actorRef

```
Actor[akka://Ping-Pong/user/gamer1#56928223]
Actor[akka://Ping-Pong/user/gamer1#56928223]
```

Because as discussed in the comments, when i use ask ? pattern, the sender() is temp actor under /temp . From [akka doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/general/addressing.html) :

> "/temp" is the guardian for all short-lived system-created actors,
>   e.g. those which are used in the implementation of ActorRef.ask.

So using tell i think you should use ActorRef